# Lex/Yacc: using global variables and finding the longest occurance

Tags: regex, compiler-construction, yacc, lex, flex-lexer

I am trying to find the longest word that is composed of alphabets [ghijklpqrswxyz]..
This seemed like a simple problem, but I guess I have some trouble understanding how
lex/yaac works. I'm testing this with a linux /usr/share/dict/words file, and the program
simple returns the whole list of words instead of printing the longest one..

```
% lex example.l
% cc lex.yy.c -ll
% ./a.out < /usr/share/dict/words
```

What seems to be the problem??

```
%{
char* longest="";
%}

%option noyywrap

%%
^[ghijklpqrswxyz]+$    {if (strlen(yytext)>strlen(longest)) {longest = yytext;}}
.|\n    {;}
%%

int main(void)
{
    yylex();
    printf("The longest matching word: %s\n", longest);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of `yytext` gets overwritten.  You will need to duplicate and copy the value rather than simply assigning it:

```
longest = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(yytext)); strcpy(longest, yytext);
```

Keep in mind that you will want to cleanup (free) successive values of `longest`.  But be careful to not `free` the statically assigned value `longest = "";` !

Comment: It would seem a fixed sized buffer (eg. `char longest[1024];`) would be simpler and avoid problems with memory leaks.  You would have to check for overflow, however.

Answer (score 1):

This program is the corrected version of your program.
It runs accurately.

```
%option noyywrap
%{
char* longest="";
%}
%%
[a-zA-Z]* {if(strlen(yytext)>strlen(longest)) longest = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(yytext)); strcpy(longest, yytext);}
%%
int main(void)
{
yylex();
printf("The longest matching word: %s\n", longest);
return 0;
}
```